# Change color of textarea placeholder onclick

Tags: html, css

Assuming I have a button and a textarea. The normal state of textarea placeholder is gray. When click on the button it should change the placeholder to black. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem that you're facing. It will help understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::placeholder` is the pseudo class that will control the placeholder text of an input... You can set this in a class and then toggle the class or add the class to your element on click.

```js
let ta = document.getElementById('ta')

function changeTAText(){
  // the following would toggle on each click
  //=> ta.classList.toggle('placeHolderText')
  // The following would add it without the
  // ability to toggle on click
  ta.classList = 'placeHolderText';
}

btn.addEventListener("click", changeTAText)
```

```css
.placeHolderText::placeholder {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" placeholder="enter your text here"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Change Color of Placeholder Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will post the partial code to make the placeholder red. Add a button and toggle the class of textarea `placeholder-red` on button click.

```css
textarea.placeholder-red::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="placeholder-red" placeholder="Describe yourself here..."></textarea>
```